# State preservation and restoration strategies with Core Data objects in a UIManagedDocument

Tags: ios, nsmanagedobject, uimanageddocument, uikit-state-preservation

I'm starting to try and add support for state preservation and restoration to my iOS app, which has a Core Data component to it that I access via a UIManagedDocument.

I'm starting to add the restoration identifiers to my view controllers, and have hooked up the required functions (currently empty) within my AppDelegate, and controllers.

I have an object that could potentially be referenced by multiple view controllers so I plan to try and preserve and restore this within my AppDelegate and just have the relevant view controllers retrieve the object from the AppDelegate. Timing of this could be tricky as the app delegate method didRecodeRestorableState occurs after all the views have already called their own decodeRestorableStateWithCoder methods.

My main problem though is that this shared class as well as multiple ViewControllers all want to have NSManagedObject properties preserved and restored. I hope to be able to use the object's URIRepresentation to facilitate this but the problem I have is my AppDelegate will open my UIManagedDocument within my AppDelegate's willFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. It does this via the UIManagedDocument openWithCompletionHandler method. Due to the threading of this opening the document is successfully opened after all my views and app delegate have already tried to restore their saved state. The AppDelegate does send a notification out once the document is ready for use, so all my view controllers can listen to this notification.

I guess I just wonder is this the best, or even only strategy for dealing with this. My objects will need to hold onto the URIRepresentations that they restore and only once the document (and it's NSManagedObjectContext) is ready try to actually find and set the corresponding NSManagedObjects up that they saved out. As such the restoring is happening a lot later than the calls to perform the restoring would I assume usually perform all their restoring work. I worry whether a controller may potentially appear empty for a brief period of time whilst it waits for the document to open and then get properly initialised.

Is there any purpose in blocking and delaying the opening of my document in this case so yes the app takes longer to open but can at least restore more correctly with all the data required before any views appear. Are there any timers being ran to make sure certain methods don't take too long? Would it be more correct to show a different view whilst we're in this limbo state, not quite sure how to go about this but its the sort of thing you may see with other apps like say the Facebook app which is dependant on a network connection.

I can't seem to find any real explanation of this sort of issue within the documentation so far.

Any help is as always very much appreciated! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In the end I just implemented notifications from when my UIManagedDocument had finished loading. These were picked up by all controllers that had coredata managed objects it wanted to restore. During restoration I keep hold of the encoded URIs, and later when receiving this UIManagedDocument ready notification I just decoded the URIs to their respective managed objects.

The problem with the shared object that I described I solved by encoded and restoring in one place from my appDelegate and then using another notification out to systems to tell them that this shared object was now fully decoded and available for use.

Not ideal and involved creating quite a lot of hierarchies of methods to ensure all objects were decoded correctly but it works ok.

Sadly since then I've hit a stumbling block where UIDataSourceModelAssociation protocol methods are being called by the OS before my UIManagedDocument has finished opening. Sadly this means that I'm unable to do anything useful. So what i really need to do somehow is defer my app restoration until everything is loaded from a CoreData UIManagedDocument POV. That problem continues...